# Swift 3.1 How to insert image as base64 into body of HTTPS request

Tags: https, swift3, base64

I want to send an image to server using HTTPS POST request. I need to send image as base64 data. I have converted image data to base64 encoded string, but I cannot convert it to Data to put it into httpBody.

```
    //encode image to base64
    let chosenImage = imageView.image
    let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(chosenImage!)! as NSData
    let strBase64 = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
    let dataBase64: Data = Data(strBase64)


    let uploadUrlString = "https://api.imgur.com/3/upload"
    let uploadUrl = NSURL(string: uploadUrlString)
    let uploadRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: uploadUrl! as URL)
    uploadRequest.addValue("Client-ID f7e5521d5dd4245", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    uploadRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    uploadRequest.httpBody = imageData
    let uploadSession = URLSession.shared
    let postRequest = uploadSession.dataTask(with: uploadRequest as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let antwort = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            let code = antwort.statusCode
            print(code)
        }
    }
    postRequest.resume()
```

Saw some solutions on StakOverflow, but didn't get how to do it properly.
Please advise.

Comment: You need to use JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject) to convert your json object to data

Comment: your json top level object should be a dictionary or an array

Comment: In Swift 3 you should use URLRequest instead of NSMutableURLRequest. You just need to declare it as var. It would be better to use JPEG instead of PNG. Note that PNG doesn't save the image orientation

Comment: `if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) {
    let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedString

}`

Comment: Well, thanks. I have changed it to URLRequest. And I tried one more time without base64 conversion - it works fine. I have used json to get body of response where imgur returned me link to the uploaded image. So now it works (more or less correct). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have changed code a bit according to some advised from Leo Dabus. And I have ensured that it works fine without any conversion to base64:

```
    let chosenImage = imageView.image
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage!, 1)
    let uploadUrlString = "https://api.imgur.com/3/upload"
    let uploadUrl = URL(string: uploadUrlString)

    var postRequest = URLRequest.init(url: uploadUrl!)
    postRequest.addValue("Client-ID XXXXXX", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    postRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    postRequest.httpBody = imageData

    let uploadSession = URLSession.shared
    let executePostRequest = uploadSession.dataTask(with: postRequest as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        {
            print(response.statusCode)
        }
        if let data = data
        {
            let json = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            print("Response data: \(String(describing: json))")
        }
    }
    executePostRequest.resume()
```

So when uploading an image, I'm getting body of the result in json and it shows me the link to uploaded image:

```
"link\":\"http:\\/\\/i.imgur.com\\/ePOUIyN.jpg\"},\"success\":true,\"status\":200}")
```

Comment: `postRequest as URLRequest` doesn't make any sense casting from URLRequest to URLRequest. change it to `uploadSession.dataTask(with: postRequest) { data, response, error in`

Comment: and add `guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }`

Comment: and shorter `let json = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)`

Comment: Thanks, mate! Helpful!

Comment: I'm beginner in programming, have 10 years background in IT, support level 3, but never developed apps by myself after graduation.

Comment: Glad to help buddy

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem ... here is my solution to insert BASE64 String into email-body:
//SWIFT 3.x

```
//convert to Data


 let image = UIImage(data: yourUIImage!  as Data)


//convert to base64 String 
 let imageData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)! as NSData


 let imageStr = imageData.base64EncodedString(options:.endLineWithCarriageReturn)


   // insert this into your HTML code 
 let tmpHTMLimage  = "<img class=\"no-show\" src=\"data:image/png;base64," + imageStr + "\" alt=\"Image\"  height=\"80\" width=\"80\"/>"
```

- solution: use .endLineWithCarriageReturn and not
  .lineLength64Characters!!!

  I realy hope this will help some of you guys!